# how to return position of spinner so that the selected option can be selected again

Tags: android, spinner

Please help guys,..
I have dialogprogress and be showing if item spinner selected.
after click the selected item in spinner can be call again of the dialogprogress on same item selected..

```
spinopr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
                            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    if (position != 0 && ni != null) {
                        new TransaksiPulsaAsync().execute();
                    } else if (position != 0 && ni == null) {
                        showToast("Koneksi Data tidak tersambung!");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // bikin apa
                }
            });
```

Comment: there are many ways to store you selected index, either by setting global variable, or in a single instance class

Comment: Don't understand anything of this. Moreover i see no question(s).

Comment: if i understood you, you mean you select item 1, and you want to keep the spinner selection lock on item 1? is that what you mean?

Comment: @greenapps return position item spinner so that can be click on same item selected

Comment: @Elltz showing again the dialogprogress on same selected item in spinner

Comment: spinner can't be return on same position after click selected item, therefore I ask here

Comment: @Ashadi,I think you have to define custom interface which call back from onPostExecute with return selected index which pass to async task.

Comment: your code tells me a diff thing and i derive a diff thing from your understanding, so you mean after you execute the stuff after the selection you want to get the selection and show the progress dialog again after the first one? you could always pass it to your async task and play with it there-- and why is position != 0 ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana a bit far for a solution, I thing the way out in setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: yes that right bro...
position != 0 because item 0 not for execute just title of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I've found the solution

```
public class SelectAgainSpinner extends Spinner {
OnItemSelectedListener listener;
int prevPos = -1;

public SelectAgainSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SelectAgainSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SelectAgainSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    super.setSelection(position);
    if (position == getSelectedItemPosition() && prevPos == position) {
        getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(null, null, position, 0);
    }
    prevPos = position;
}
```

}

and then put in the xml

Answer (score 0):

As per document,
Spinner's onItemSelected Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been selected. This callback is invoked only when the **newly selected position is different from the previously selected position** or if there was no selected item.

Answer (score 0):

int spinnerpos = adapter.getPosition(spinner item);

spinner item is the value of spinner item which has been selected.

spinopr.setSelection(spinnerpos);

Then onItemSelected will get invoked.